# there is a error as apxs not found and apache is not built when I build(configure) the source code of phpspreadsheet

Tags: php, apache, php-7, phpspreadsheet

[checking for Apache 2.0 handler-module support via DSO through APXS...

Sorry, I cannot run apxs.  Possible reasons follow:

1. Perl is not installed
2. apxs was not found. Try to pass the path using --with-apxs2=/path/to/apxs
3. Apache was not built using --enable-so (the apxs usage page is displayed)

The output of /usr/local/apache/bin/apxs follows:
./configure: line 6199: /usr/local/apache/bin/apxs: No such file or directory
configure: error: Aborting]

it is the error suggest me the solution for this.

Answer (score 7):

When `httpd -l` does not list `mod_so.c`, `DSO` won't work, because it's an essential prerequisite; according to the [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/apxs.html). Otherwise `APXS` can be installed with the package manager:

- `sudo dnf install httpd-devel` (CentOS)
- `sudo apt-get install apache2-dev` (Ubuntu)

This installs it as `/usr/bin/apxs` and `./configure --with-apxs` works (without passing a path). One does not even have to install `httpd` / `apache2`, in order to use it's development tools - which then can be used to configure `PHP` with `APXS`.

Comment: Amazon CentOS is `yum install httpd-devel`

Answer (score 1):

While installing Apache version greater than httpd-2.2 we have to install pcre, apr and apr-util separately and then ./configure

The right way to install **apr** and **apr-util** would be

```
cd httpd-2.4.37/srclib/apr 
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/apr/

cd ../apr-util
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/apr-util/ --with-apr=/usr/local/apr/
```

Its is better to check if there is some dependency package missing

```
cd  httpd-2.4.37
./buildconf
```

It may require to install these

```
yum install expat-devel
```

(xml/apr_xml.c:35:19: fatal error: expat.h: No such file or directory)

```
yum install libtool libtool-devel
```

(might be needed if not found in buildconf)

Now, once the buildconf finishes with 0 errors, we need to configure apache, like this

```
cd httpd-2.4.37
./configure --enable-debug --prefix=/usr/local/apache2 --with-apr=/usr/local/apr/ --with-apr-util=/usr/local/apr-util/ --with-pcre=/usr/local/pcre
```

For detailed step by step installation, Visit

[Install Latest Apache: Step by Step Procedure](http://www.infradbas.com/2018/12/install-latest-apache-step-by-step.html)

Finally, while installing php,

```
./configure --with-apxs2=/opt/software/apache2/bin/apxs --enable-mbstring --with-mysql --with-mysqli --with-ldap=/usr/local
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the apx path  `/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs`

My apache installation directory is `/usr/local/apache2`

Change directory php folder and run below command

```
./configure \
    --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs \
    --with-curl=/usr \
    --with-gd \
    --with-gettext \
    --with-jpeg-dir=/usr \
    --with-freetype-dir=/usr \
    --with-kerberos \
    --with-openssl \
    --with-mcrypt=/usr/local/lib \
    --with-mhash \
    --with-mysql=mysqlnd \
    --with-mysqli=mysqlnd \
    --with-pcre-regex \
    --with-pear \
    --with-png-dir=/usr \
    --with-xsl \
    --with-zlib \
    --with-zlib-dir=/usr \
    --with-iconv \
    --enable-bcmath \
    --enable-calendar \
    --enable-exif \
    --enable-ftp \
    --enable-gd-native-ttf \
    --enable-soap \
    --enable-sockets \
    --enable-mbstring \
    --enable-zip \
    --enable-wddx
```